# How do I end a global name?

Tags: stata

I'm trying to compose a new global variable from other global variable names like

```
global partA 1234
global partB 5678
global fullname $partA_$partB
```

However, when I do this the underscore gets interpreted as part of the first global name. My current solution to this is to create a local from `partA` and then do

```
global fullname `partA'_$partB
```

How can I concatenate the first two globals into a new global with an underscore (or other character) separating them without creating this temporary local?

Comment: "Global variable" is here strictly a solecism for global macro. In Stata terms, a variable is a column of a dataset, and macros are not variables. Naturally, from the point of view of many programming languages, a Stata macro looks like a variable and works like a variable, but that's the terminology. More in the same vein at http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-08/msg01258.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose the `global` name in `{}`, after the `$`, like so:

```
global parta 1234
global partb 5678
global fullincorrect $parta_$partb

di "$fullincorrect"


global partc 1234
global partd 5678
global fullcorrect ${partc}_${partd}

di "$fullcorrect"
```

with the result

```
. di "$fullincorrect"
5678

. di "$fullcorrect"
1234_5678
```

Answer (score 2):

This would work too:

```
. global partA 1234

. global partB 5678

. global fullname = "$partA" + "_" + "$partB" 

. di "$fullname" 
1234_5678
```

I don't especially recommend it, but it's a solution. The key idea is that the global macros hold strings and `+` concatenates strings. A key detail is that the quotation marks can't be part of a macro name. It's only because an underscore can be part of a macro name that this problem bites.